# Creating a scope with a query from a method on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a scope on a Model at my project, but I want that the query filter the elements basead on a method at my Model.

This is my model:

```
class Talent < ApplicationRecord
  scope :public_profile, -> { Talent.all.select{ |t| t.age > 13 } }

def age
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - self.birth_date.year - ((now.month > self.birth_date.month || 
  (now.month == self.birth_date.month && now.day >= self.birth_date.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

When I try to run this scope I get the error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
    from app/models/talent.rb:195:in `age'
    from (irb):6:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):6
```

The line 195 its on my method age. So, probably when doing the select, my element is coming nil.

What Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
```

And given that you're only calling the method `year` twice in the `age` method:

```
def age
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - self.birth_date.year - ((now.month > self.birth_date.month || 
  (now.month == self.birth_date.month && now.day >= self.birth_date.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

And given that `now` is certain not to be `nil`:

```
now = Time.now.utc.to_date
```

It would seem that `self.birth_date` is returning `nil`. And, as the error states, `nil` doesn't have the `year` method.

Comment: Exactly. So, the scope of self doesnt work when called from a scope? Should I create a method with a paramether and pass the object to the method?

Comment: @FernandoMaymone this has nothing to do with the scope of `self` this has to do with the fact that one of your records does not have a `birth_date`. That being said `select` will return an `Array` and a scope should always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` so that is going to cause an issue

Comment: Exactly. The problem was the birth_date comming nil. Thanks guys